# how to pass a str and a dictory using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, salt-stack

I am trying to update our salt grain for our servers base on the `AppId`. The `AppId` has to be a `dict` in order to set the grains.

```
host1 = "someAppServer.com"
appId = {'AppID':['55661']}



subprocess.check_output(["salt " + host1 + " grains.setvals " + eos])
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
subprocess.check_output(["salt " + host1 + " grains.setvals " + eos])
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'dict' objects
```

Comment: What is `eos`? Looks like this should raise a `NameError`

Comment: sorry.. eos suppose to be appId. I forgot to update before pasting it.

Comment: Don't pass a single string in a list, pass a list like `['salt', 'host1', 'grains.setvals', ...]`. Then, what exactly is the last argument supposed to look like? It has to be some string (or strings) you create *from* the `dict`, not the `dict` itself.

Comment: Apart from you probably should pass an exec vector (`list` of cmd and args), you'll need to serialize the dict for the execution... in a form the application understands. `str()` or `json.dumps()` or ?...

Comment: Thank you. I think I figured it out. :)